# Failed graphic insertion

Tags: graphics

When I create the pdf all I obtain is a frame with the name of the image instead of the image itself. Here’s the code I’m using :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,draft]{article} 

%Packages importants>>>>>>>>>
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[francais]{babel}                
\usepackage{amsmath}                        
\usepackage{amsfonts}                       
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}                         
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                       
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/dad/Desktop/projet_recherche}}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{car}\\
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Is there something I should omit or add?

Comment: Remove the `draft` option at the `\documentclass` option list. `draft` causes  showing the frame only, in order to speed up the compilation

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It worked! Thank you! 
Is there a way to keep the draft option and still have the graphics appear?

Comment: I know of no quick and easy one. The `draft` option is handled to `graphicx` package (which is finally responsible for the frame being drawn)

Comment: @Gunelle Can you elaborate why you want to keep the draft option? There may be workarounds.